# Calculating $H_2(T_f,\Bbb Z)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm currently trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $\Sigma$ be a closed orientable surface of genus $2$ and $f:\Sigma\to \Sigma$ be a homeomorphism inducing isomorphisms $A:H_1(\Sigma,\Bbb Z)\to H_1(\Sigma,\Bbb Z)$ and $1:H_2(\Sigma,\Bbb Z)\to H_2(\Sigma,\Bbb Z)$. Let $Z$ be a mapping torus of $f$, i.e, $Z = \Sigma\times I/(x,0)\sim (f(x),1)$. Compute $H_*(Z,\Bbb Z)$.

My attempt: For mapping torus $Z$ we have a l.e.s.
$$\cdots\to H_n(\Sigma)\xrightarrow{f_*-1}H_n(\Sigma)\xrightarrow{\iota_*}H_n(Z)\to\cdots.$$
Recall that the homology of $\Sigma$ is the following:
$$H_n(\Sigma) = \begin{cases}
\Bbb Z & n = 0,2\\
\Bbb Z^4 & n =1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$
From the l.e.s. we conclude $H_n(Z) =0 $ for $n>3$ and $H_3(Z)\simeq\Bbb Z$. Since $Z$ is path-connected, $H_0(Z)\simeq\Bbb Z$. The problem is computing degree $2$ and $1$. The above l.e.s. breaks to the following exact sequence
$$0\to H_2(\Sigma)\xrightarrow{\iota_*} H_2(Z)\to H_1(\Sigma)\xrightarrow{A-1}H_1(\Sigma)\xrightarrow{\iota_*}H_1(Z)\to H_0(\Sigma)\to 0.$$
If $A -1 =0$ or isomorphism then using splitting lemma, I can compute $H_2$ and $H_1$. But if $A-1\neq 0$ is not an isomorphism, then I wonder if it's possible to express $H_2$ and $H_1$ as in terms of $A$. Is it possible or is it undecidable?

Comment: $H_0(\Sigma) \rightarrow H_0(\Sigma)$ is null ($H_0$ is exactly the space of connected components) , and $Z$ is connected, so $H_0(Z)=\mathbb{Z}$ and you can instead consider the exact sequence ending at the first $H_0(\Sigma)$. The first term is incorrect (it should be $H_2(\Sigma)/(f_{\ast}-1)$, I think – if $f$ is the identity on $H_2(\Sigma)$, ie $f$ preserves orientation, the corresponding term is zero). Nothing in there is “indecidable” though – this word has a specific meaning. “Underspecified” would probably be closer to what you mean.

Comment: @Aphelli Ah, yes by exactness. The first term is by assumption. $f$ is orientation preserving.

Comment: Are you happy with an answer like $H_2(Z)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \operatorname{ker}(A-Id)$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Ah I see. Then $H_1(Z)\simeq\Bbb Z\oplus\operatorname{coker}(A-1)$?

Comment: Yes.  The point is that is in a short exact sequence of abelian groups $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n\rightarrow 0$ always splits.